# PHP - how to get rid of "Undefined index"

Tags: php, variables, if-statement, isset

I wasn't able to find a solid work-a-round yet for it so I thought I just might ask here.

My error.log says for a good reason

```
[error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: Variablename
```

Till now I got rid of it with using a if statement around it like

```
if (isset($var)) {
  if ($var ... ) { ... }
}
```

But now I got a lil problem so I can't use this "wrap-around" like above easily.

the check_login(...) function will write $_SESSION Variables like ['loginattempts'] or ['captchaattempts'] - now I want to let the login disappear if those attemps reach a specified amount. Like

```
if ($_SESSION['loginatt'] < x && $_SESSION['capatt'] < x) { echo 'login form...';}
```

If I would wrap a check if the variable is set around it - the login wouldn't appear if those variables are not set.

Possible work-a-rounds could be

```
if (!isset($var)) {echo 'login form ...';}
else {echo 'login form...';}
```

but that would mean I would have to have a duplicate login form in my code
I know could also just change this echo 'login form ...' into a requice_once 'include/loginform.php' - but there would be still a duplicate entry for this require_once command.

I could also set a $testvar like

```
if (isset($var)) { 
  if ($var > x) {
    echo 'acc. blocked;
    $testvar = 0;
  }
  else {
    $testvar = 1;
  }

if ($testvar < 1) {
  echo 'login form...';
}
```

So are there any other ways as those ?

If not which way you would suggest to take to keep the code as it should be for "good programming" ?

Any statements are welcome, thanks for helping out

Kris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, it's always a good idea to output all errors during development and to always have initialized values. It can get rid of some bugs as you will always have a default value to fall back on.

An easy way to fix your problem is to use another variable and to add your `$_SESSION` variables only if they exist. For instance:

```
$login_attempts = 0;
if (isset($_SESSION['loginattempts'])) {
    $login_attempts = $_SESSION['loginattempts'];
}
```

Alternatively, a ternary expression is also possible for compactness, although with the long *loginattempts* index this looks a little harsh, in my opinion.

```
$login_attempts = (isset($_SESSION['loginattempts'])) ? $_SESSION['loginattempts'] : 0;
```

Comment: Thanks - gave me a good impression - ternary expressions here look quite nice to keep the code neat. About the Sessionindex : its not exactly that name - I just took an example name to keep the topic more clear :)

Comment: @Kris I agree – ternary expressions are neat if you have a lot of variables to initialize. If we were to nitpick about efficiency, the code in my first block would always first write `0` to `$login_attempts`, while the ternary variant would directly take the correct value (unless it gets optimized anyway). Either way, I doubt it's worth losing sleep over. Good luck with your project!

Comment: Well true - whatever solution I might take - it won't harm the perfomance in a "real" way. It's just the that I want to keep it was clean as possible and keep it simple as much as possible if other programmer have to modify my code :)

Answer (score 0):

**Start defining indexes!**

you can directly check if session vars are set or not

```
if (isset ($_SESSION['loginatt'])) { /* action here */ }
```

if you want to reduce redundancy in use of login form string
you can declare it under a variable, like

```
$loginform = '<form action="" ...>';
$loginform .= '<input type='"...>';
```

and `echo` it anywhere you want.